# How do I read/write ListView ItemTemplate field using jQuery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, listview

I have been struggling with this, so I put together a stripped down version to show the problems I am having.

Start with a generic class like the **Member** class shown below:

```
public class Member
{

    public Member()
    {
        Number = String.Empty;
        Name = String.Empty;
        Email = String.Empty;
        Phone = String.Empty;
    }
    public String Number { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Email { get; set; }
    public String Phone { get; set; }
    public String LinkNumber
    {
        get
        {
            var result = String.Empty;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Number))
            {
                result = String.Format("<a class=\"showpopup\" id=\"{0}\">{0}</a>", Number);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

}
```

I want to display that in an ASP.NET Framework 4.6 WebForm using a [ListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.aspx) control.

ASIDE:
Is there a JSFiddle tool that works with ASP.NET? I can't get the ASP.NET to render there, so I post the HTML here, in sections.

In the **HEAD** of the document, I have some simple javascript and CSS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('div.popup_hider').hide();
        $('div.popup_box').hide();
        //on click hide the message and the
        //on click show the hider div and the message
        $('.showpopup').click(function () {
            $('div.popup_hider').fadeIn("slow");
            $('div.popup_box').fadeIn("slow");
            $('tdMember').val($('#<%=lnkMemberNumber.ClientID%>').val());
            $('tdName').val($('#<%=lnkMemberName.ClientID%>').val());
            $('tdPhone').val($('#<%=lnkMemberPhone.ClientID%>').val());
            $('tdEmail').val($('#<%=lnkMemberEmail.ClientID%>').val());
        });
        $('#tdCancel').click(function () {
            $('div.popup_hider').fadeOut("slow");
            $('div.popup_box').fadeOut("slow");
        });
        $('#tdSave').click(function () {
            $('div.popup_hider').fadeOut("slow");
            $('div.popup_box').fadeOut("slow");
            $('lnkMemberNumber').val($('tdMember').val());
            $('lnkMemberName').val($('tdName').val());
            $('lnkMemberPhone').val($('tdPhone').val());
            $('lnkMemberEmail').val($('tdEmail').val());
        });
    });
</script>
<style>
    div.popup_box {
        background-color: #888888;
        display: table;
        filter: alpha(opacity=100);
        border: 1px solid #999999;
        margin: auto; 
        opacity: 1;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 11;
        -moz-opacity: 1;
    }
    div.popup_hider {
        background-color: #004392;
        filter: alpha(opacity=55);
        height: 100%;
        left: 0px;
        opacity: .55;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 10;
        -moz-opacity:.55;
    }
</style>
```

The controls referenced above are defined in the HTML below:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div class="popup_hider"></div>
        <div class="popup_box">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Member:<br /><input type="text" id="tdMember" /></td>
                    <td>Name<br /><input type="text" id="tdName" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Phone:<br /><input type="tel" id="tdPhone" /></td>
                    <td>Email:<br /><input type="email" id="tdEmail" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><a id="tdSave">Save</a></td>
                    <td><a id="tdCancel">Cancel</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <asp:ListView ID="listView1" runat="server">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkMemberNumber">Member</asp:LinkButton></th>
                        <th><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkMemberName">Name</asp:LinkButton></th>
                        <th><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkMemberPhone">Phone</asp:LinkButton></th>
                        <th><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkMemberEmail">Email</asp:LinkButton></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" class="listview"></tr>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td><asp:Label runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="lblMemberNumber"><%#Eval("LinkNumber") %></asp:Label></td>
                    <td><asp:Label runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="lblMemberName"><%#Eval("Name") %></asp:Label></td>
                    <td><asp:Label runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="lblMemberPhone"><%#Eval("Phone") %></asp:Label></td>
                    <td><asp:Label runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="lblMemberEmail"><%#Eval("Email") %></asp:Label></td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

That is how every page I see shows how to access ASP.NET controls with jQuery; however, the ASP.NET controls referenced in the head section are part of the **ItemTemplate**, so are not actually visible inside the HTML:

```
$('tdMember').val($('#<%=lnkMemberNumber.ClientID%>').val());
$('tdName').val($('#<%=lnkMemberName.ClientID%>').val());
$('tdPhone').val($('#<%=lnkMemberPhone.ClientID%>').val());
$('tdEmail').val($('#<%=lblEmail.ClientID%>').val());
```

If you put that into a Visual Studio 2015 project, you will see Red Squiggly lines that read:

> The name 'xxx' does not exist in the current context

You get a **Compilation Error** with the same message if you try running it.

So, how can I read (and eventually write) values from a [ListView ItemTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemtemplate.aspx) control to HTML using jQuery?

To make this simple, I populated static data in the Page_Load event:

```
private List<Member> _roster;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (_roster == null)
        {
            _roster = new List<Member>();
            _roster.Add(new Member() { Name = "John Doe", Number = "ABC123", Email = "jdoe@email.com", Phone = "5551234" });
            _roster.Add(new Member() { Name = "Jane Doe", Number = "ABC124", Email = "janed@email.com", Phone = "5551111" });
            _roster.Add(new Member() { Name = "Jenny", Number = "ABC1233", Email = "jenny@hotmail.com", Phone = "8675309" });
        }
        listView1.DataSource = _roster;
        listView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

### Solved!

https://jsfiddle.net/jp2code/z7tpuagf/

This should be a working example below. It does not have any ASP.NET in it, but it is what Visual Studio will compile the ASP.NET controls down to.

```js
var rowNumber;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div.popup_hider').hide();
    $('div.popup_box').hide();
    $('[id^=listRow_]').click(function () {
        //loop al span elements in the td and fill the textboxes
        $(this).find('td span').each(function (index, value) {
            if (index == 0) {
                $("#tdMember").val($(value).text());
            } else if (index == 1) {
                $("#tdName").val($(value).text());
            } else if (index == 2) {
                $("#tdPhone").val($(value).text());
            } else if (index == 3) {
                $("#tdEmail").val($(value).text());
            }
        });
        // get row number to hardcode the elements
        rowNumber = this.id.split("_")[1];
    });
    //on click hide the message and the
    //on click show the hider div and the message
    $('.showpopup').click(function () {
        $('div.popup_hider').fadeIn("slow");
        $('div.popup_box').fadeIn("slow");
    });
    $('#tdCancel').click(function () {
        $('div.popup_hider').fadeOut("slow");
        $('div.popup_box').fadeOut("slow");
    });
    $('#tdSave').click(function () {
        $('div.popup_hider').fadeOut("slow");
        $('div.popup_box').fadeOut("slow");
        //and now we do the reverse, find the row ID with listRow_ + rowNumber and update the values in the cell
        $('#listRow_' + rowNumber).find('td span').each(function (index, value) {
            if (index == 0) {
                $(value).text($("#tdMember").val());
            } else if (index == 1) {
                $(value).text($("#tdName").val());
            } else if (index == 2) {
                $(value).text($("#tdPhone").val());
            } else if (index == 3) {
                $(value).text($("#tdEmail").val());
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```css
a.fake-link {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
div.popup_box {
  background-color: #888888;
  display: table;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  margin: auto; 
  opacity: 1;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 11;
  -moz-opacity: 1;
}
div.popup_hider {
  background-color: #004392;
  filter: alpha(opacity=55);
  height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  opacity: .55;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  -moz-opacity:.55;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="popup_hider" style="display: none;"></div>
  <div class="popup_box" style="display: none;">
    <table>
      <tbody><tr>
        <td>Member:<br><input type="text" id="tdMember"></td>
        <td>Name<br><input type="text" id="tdName"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Phone:<br><input type="tel" id="tdPhone"></td>
        <td>Email:<br><input type="email" id="tdEmail"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a id="tdSave" class="fake-link">Save</a></td>
        <td><a id="tdCancel" class="fake-link">Cancel</a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody></table>
  </div>
  <table border="1">
    <tbody><tr>
      <th><a id="listView1_lnkMemberNumber" href="javascript:__doPostBack('listView1$lnkMemberNumber','')">Member</a></th>
      <th><a id="listView1_lnkMemberName" href="javascript:__doPostBack('listView1$lnkMemberName','')">Name</a></th>
      <th><a id="listView1_lnkMemberPhone" href="javascript:__doPostBack('listView1$lnkMemberPhone','')">Phone</a></th>
      <th><a id="listView1_lnkMemberEmail" href="javascript:__doPostBack('listView1$lnkMemberEmail','')">Email</a></th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="listRow_0" class="listRow">
      <td><a class="fake-link"><span id="listView1_lblMemberNumber_0" class="showpopup">ABC123</span></a></td>
      <td><span id="listView1_lblMemberName_0">John Doe</span></td>
      <td><span id="listView1_lblMemberPhone_0">5551234</span></td>
      <td><span id="listView1_lblMemberEmail_0">jdoe@email.com</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="listRow_1" class="listRow">
      <td><a class="fake-link"><span id="listView1_lblMemberNumber_1" class="showpopup">ABC124</span></a></td>
      <td><span id="listView1_lblMemberName_1">Jane Doe</span></td>
      <td><span id="listView1_lblMemberPhone_1">5551111</span></td>
      <td><span id="listView1_lblMemberEmail_1">janed@email.com</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="listRow_2" class="listRow">
      <td><a class="fake-link"><span id="listView1_lblMemberNumber_2" class="showpopup">ABC321</span></a></td>
      <td><span id="listView1_lblMemberName_2">Jenny</span></td>
      <td><span id="listView1_lblMemberPhone_2">8675309</span></td>
      <td><span id="listView1_lblMemberEmail_2">jenny@hotmail.com</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody></table>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know how to specify a version of jQuery in the header for the StackOverflow *Run code snipped* tool, so the posted solution doesn't work here. See the JsFiddle link for a working demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example.
Add a unique class name and ID to the `<tr>` by using the row index from the ListView.

```
<tr id="listRow_<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" class="listRow">
```

Then the jQuery can bind the onclick event to the row and loop the `<span>` elements in the table cells.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.listRow').click(function () {
            //loop al span elements in the td
            $(this).find('td span').each(function (index, value) {
                alert($(value).text());
            });
            //or use the row number to do stuff and hardcode the elements
            var rowNumber = this.id.split("_")[1];
            var lbl1 = "mainContentPane_listView1_lblMemberEmail_" + rowNumber;
            alert($("#" + lbl1).text());
        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem is that you are using `ClientIDMode="Static"`. Normally a ListView (and all other controls that loop data to generate content) will create a unique id per row and control within the row. That looks something like this:
`mainContentPane_listView1_lblMemberName_1`.

That is why you are getting the errors when using `<%=lnkMemberNumber.ClientID%>`. It does not exist outside of the ListView and thus is not accessible, even with a static ClientID.

Also enabling `ClientIDMode="Static"` in a repeater element will result in multiple ID's that are exactly the same and that is not what you want.

**UPDATE**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //set the rowNumber as global variable
    var rowNumber;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.listRow').click(function () {
            //loop al span elements in the td and fill the textboxes
            $(this).find('td span').each(function (index, value) {
                if (index == 0) {
                    $("#tdMember").val($(value).text());
                } else if (index == 1) {
                    $("#tdName").val($(value).text());
                } else if (index == 2) {
                    $("#tdPhone").val($(value).text());
                } else if (index == 3) {
                    $("#tdEmail").val($(value).text());
                }
            });
            //or use the row number to do stuff and hardcode the elements, but we'll use the rowNumber later
            rowNumber = this.id.split("_")[1];
            var lbl1 = "mainContentPane_listView1_lblMemberEmail_" + rowNumber;
            var lbl1Text = $("#" + lbl1).text();
        });

        $('#tdSave').click(function () {
            $('div.popup_hider').fadeOut("slow");
            $('div.popup_box').fadeOut("slow");

            //and now we do the reverse, find the row ID with listRow_ + rowNumber and update the values in the cell
            $('#listRow_' + rowNumber).find('td span').each(function (index, value) {
                if (index == 0) {
                    $(value).text($("#tdMember").val());
                } else if (index == 1) {
                    $(value).text($("#tdName").val());
                } else if (index == 2) {
                    $(value).text($("#tdPhone").val());
                } else if (index == 3) {
                    $(value).text($("#tdEmail").val());
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: OK. I came across a tutorial that said to use `ClientIDMode="Static"`. It didn't do everything exactly as I did, though. Let me see what removing that does, and I will report back.

Comment: I changed `$('.listRow').click` section to `$('[id^=listRow_]').click`, verified the *alert()* messages, got the `rowNumber` variable, and set those values to my various "td" fields. When the popup box shows, though, all of the textboxes are still empty. :(

Comment: Updated my answer. It copies the content to the cell to the textboxes and copy them back when the save button is clicked. Although these new values will not be accessible on postback. You might even get a `Invalid postback or callback argument` exeption.

Comment: Beautiful! I will update my question with a Fiddle solution from your help.